# ToolStripCombobox.SelectionChangeCommitted not found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two `ToolStripCombobox` controls, each with `SelectedIndexChanged` listeners attached.

I'm facing a problem when I modify the item collection programmatically. I end up triggering the SelectedIndexChanged unwillingly.

When searching online for a solution I found [OnSelectionChangeCommitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.onselectionchangecommitted(v=vs.100).aspx)  and the corrensponding event, but Visual studio says:

```
'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

If it is impossible to make use of `SelectionChangeCommitted`, what other ways are there to avoid triggering events when manually updating ToolStripComboBox items?

Im using .Net 4.0 and the `ToolStripComboBox` is configured with `DropDownStyle = DropDownList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it from underlying ComboBox.

```
toolStripComboBoxExample.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += ComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted;

private void ComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted(object o, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    \\Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer because it provides a direct answer to the original question and is the best solution for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do your stuff inside `SelectedIndexChanged` event itself. By declaring a global `bool` variable and checking it from `SelectedIndexChanged` event to verify the type of trigger, you can achieve this. That is something as like,

```
    bool isManualFire = true;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear isManualFire flag in case of programatical changes
        isManualFire = false;

        //Do programatic changes on toolStripComboBox1

        //Set it back to get manual triggerings
        isManualFire = true;
    }

    private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isManualFire)
        {
            //DO some operations
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: People have to use SelectionChangeCommitted because SelectedIndexChanged doesn't detect change after the dropdown is closed without selecting an item. SelectionChangeCommitted can recognize clicking on an item before the dropdown is closed.

Comment: @RayChakrit Yes, that's true but I hope you read what the op has mentioned in the question.

"If it is impossible to make use of SelectionChangeCommitted, what other ways are there to avoid triggering events when manually updating ToolStripComboBox items?"

He asked about the other ways of achieving selection change.