# Toolstrip combobox onselectionchangecommitted not working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling, toolstrip

I'm trying to trigger some code when a user makes a mouse selection in a toolstrip combobox on a winform and have been trying to get the `OnSelectionChangeCommitted` to work (link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.onselectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx)) similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028014/toolstripcombobox-selectionchangecommitted-not-found/30028590#30028590) question. I can't use the `SelectedIndexChanged` method because the first item is selected automatically when a user clicks on the combobox which then triggers the code, and I'd prefer not to use focus or a boolean.

The code below doesn't trigger when the user makes a selection in the combobox, what am I doing wrong?

```
protected virtual void bxDEAL_SELECT_OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("onselect value changed");
        }
```

Comment: That method signature is wrong.  It is missing the `Object sender` parameter.  You cannot have hooked this method to an event or it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your sender parameter?

It should look something like this

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // your code
}
```

Comment: did you try puting if statement inside slectedIndexChanged?

Comment: place an integer value -1 outside the event and check if selectedIndex = value if it's not that value you can run your code... then set value = slectedIndex

Comment: The handler isn't hooked up, or the missing `sender` parameter would have triggered a compiler error.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I agree, I couldn't find the ``OnSelectionChangeCommitted`` event listed in the combobox properties/events so I typed it in manually. I guess this doesn't hook it up. What's the correct method?

Comment: comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted += comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted;

Comment: thanks but I get a compile error on ``bxDEAL_SELECT.SelectionChangeCommitted += bxDEAL_SELECT_SelectionChangeCommitted; Error CS1061 'ToolStripComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectionChangeCommitted' and no extension method 'SelectionChangeCommitted' accepting a first argument of type 'ToolStripComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ``

Comment: also shouldn't it be ``OnSelectionChangeCommitted`` instead of ``SelectionChangeCommitted``?

Comment: if i use ``bxDEAL_SELECT.OnSelectionChangeCommitted += bxDEAL_SELECT_OnSelectionChangeCommitted;`` i get a compile error ``Error CS0122 ToolStripComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level``

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the underlying ComboBox object to access the committed event.

```
bxDEAL_SELECT.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += ComboBoxOnSelectionChangeCommitted;

private void bxDEAL_SELECT_OnSelectionChangeCommitted(object o, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    \\Your code goes here.
}
```